# Loop through pd.Series with Dask

Tags: python, string, pandas, dask

I have two pd.Series.

**Series_A** contains strings.

**Series_B** contains sub-strings of Series_A and is sorted by character length.

I now want to replace the parts of strings from Series_A which are listed in Series_B (see the code below).

I would like to use the Dask library to speed up the process, but I don't know how I would do that. Especially if I should partion Series_A or Series_B or both.

```
#input data (simplified)
Series_A = pd.Series(data=["AAAABC","AAABC","AAACBC"]) #real data: 50.000 strings
Series_B = pd.Series(data=["AAAA","ABC","BC"]) #real data: 800.000 strings

#loop
for element in Series_B:
    Series_A = Series_A.map(lambda x: x.replace(element,""))

#expected output
Series_A_output = pd.Series(data=["","AA","AAAC"])
```

**EDIT:**

I experimented a bit with the suggestions, currently the previous Loop/map appraoch seems to be still the fastest. Am I doing something wrong?

```
# =============================================================================
# libraries
# =============================================================================

import dask.dataframe as dd
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

# =============================================================================
# prepare experiment
# =============================================================================

s1 = pd.Series(data=["AAAABC","AAABC","AAACBC"]*(100)) #real data: 50.000 strings
s2 = pd.Series(data=["AAAA","ABC","BC"]*(100)) #real data: 800.000 strings

s1 = s1.to_frame()
s1["matched"] = ""
s1["combined"] = list(zip(s1.iloc[:,0], s1["matched"]))

s1_backup = s1.copy()

# =============================================================================
# custom functions
# =============================================================================

def replacer(x):
    k = 0 
    l = len(s2)
    while len(x) > 0 and k < l:
        x = x.replace(s2[k], "")
        k += 1
    return x

#=========================================================================
# pandas Legacy
# =============================================================================
s1 = s1_backup.copy()
start = time.time()

for element in s2:
    s1["combined"] = s1["combined"].map(lambda x: (x[0].replace(element, ""),""))

end = time.time()
print("Process took: {0:2.2f}min to complete.".format((end-start)/60))
print("Process analyzed: {0:2.0f} elements.".format(len(s1)))
print("Process took: {0:2.4f}s per element.".format((end-start)/len(s1)))
#print('''Process took: 0.00min to complete.
#Process analyzed: 300 elements.
#Process took: 0.0007s per element.''')

#=========================================================================
# pandas with new replacer function
# =============================================================================
s1 = s1_backup.copy()
start = time.time()

for element in s2:
    s1["combined"] = s1["combined"].map(lambda x: (replacer(x[0]),""))

end = time.time()
print("Process took: {0:2.2f}min to complete.".format((end-start)/60))
print("Process analyzed: {0:2.0f} elements.".format(len(s1)))
print("Process took: {0:2.4f}s per element.".format((end-start)/len(s1)))
#print('''Process took: 4.79min to complete.
#Process analyzed: 300 elements.
#Process took: 0.9585s per element.''')

# =============================================================================
# dask Legacy
# =============================================================================
s1 = s1_backup.copy()
s1 = dd.from_pandas(s1, npartitions=10)

start = time.time()

for element in s2:
    s1["combined"] = s1.map_partitions(lambda x: x["combined"].map(lambda y: (y[0].replace(element, ""),"")))

print(s1["combined"].compute())
end = time.time()
print("Process took: {0:2.2f}min to complete.".format((end-start)/60))
print("Process analyzed: {0:2.0f} elements.".format(len(s1)))
print("Process took: {0:2.4f}s per element.".format((end-start)/len(s1)))
#print('''Process took: 0.14min to complete.
#Process analyzed: 300 elements.
#Process took: 0.0270s per element.''')
```

Comment: There is a tricky part here if you want to go parallel. If order of `Series_B` is not fixed the first element of `Series_A` could be `"AAA"` or `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can optimize your function: you are looping through the second series even if you already get `''`. You can consider to use a custom function.

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(data=["AAAABC", "AAABC", "AAACBC"]) #real data: 50.000 strings
s2 = pd.Series(data=["AAAA", "ABC", "BC"])
```

## Custom Function

```py
def replacer(x):
    k = 0 
    l = len(s2)
    while len(x) > 0 and k < l:
        x = x.replace(s2[k], "")
        k += 1
    return x

# and use in the following way
s1 = s1.map(replacer)
```

## Dask

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import os
# you should play with the optimal number of partitions
# if this is not a one-off job
npartitions = os.cpu_count()

s1 = dd.from_pandas(s1, npartitions=npartitions)
s1 = s1.map_partitions(lambda x: x.map(replacer)).compute()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and the Dask example. I found your custom Function very interesting, but it seem (at least for my dataset) the previous Loop/map implementation seems to be faster. I am not quite sure why or if I did a mistake. Maybe it is, because there are only a few Strings in Series_A which are fully replaceable. I now tried to convert the previous Loop implementation to dask, but this also seems to be slower which is confusing (I have edited my question).

Comment: My goal was just to show how to use dask. And I agree that it could be slower. I don't know if the `replacer` function could be improved by checking if  the string in `s1` contains any of the remaining substring in `s2` (which is huge). Maybe we can play with a mix of the two solutions or go for `multiprocessing`.